# Pair band with my Windows 10 App

Tags: windows, microsoft-band

I am quite new of Microsoft App programming. I need to use raw data of my Microsoft Band. I already done it with an Android app, but I want to replicate my program on my Windows 10 system.

Using the sample program downloaded by sdk website, I am able to receive some data but the band itself is locked in the pairing configuration. I think that is searching for the Microsoft Health app...

There are some function to configure the band in order to use it during the pairing with Windows 10?

P.S. I am using the First Version of the Microsoft Band!

Thank you,

Comment: Have you linked the Band to the device using the Health app? It could possibly be the issue.

Comment: Actually I reset my band before start to program in Windows. So now is paired just to my laptop. Do you suggest to pair with my phone and than to my laptop? Is it possible?

Comment: As long as the Band is paired correctly, you shouldn't have a problem running the sample apps. I haven't got a Band 1 to test with but this is working as expected with the Band 2

Comment: Bluetooth pairing is not enough for the Microsoft Band to go into operational mode. It's also required to link it with the Microsoft Health app.

Comment: Yes I suppose that was the problem... Do you mind if there is a way to pair both with Microsoft app and my windows 10 app (not in the same time), in order to go into operational mode?

Comment: Ok I solved... An application called: "Microsoft Band Sync" is needed!

Answer (score 1):

After a Band has been reset, you must use either the Microsoft Health application (on a phone) or the Microsoft Band Sync app (on a desktop) to initially setup the Band (i.e. take it out of its reset mode).  This involves linking the Band to a Microsoft Health account.  However, after that, the Band can be manually Bluetooth-paired to another device (phone or desktop) and then used independently of Microsoft Health.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please direct me how to retrieve data from the band in windows? I downloaded the band sdk and when i run the code, its reading only the accelerator data but i dont know where its stored.